# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') matrix transpose problem

Tags: javascript

```
function transpose(matrix) {
  var transposed = [],
    rows = matrix.length,
    cols = matrix[0].length;

  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    transposed[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      transposed[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
    }
  }

  return transposed;
}

let result = transpose([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]);
console.log(result)
```

I'm not understanding the error because I've initialized transposed[i]=[] as well as transposed=[]. There should be no error. Please help me fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the definitions of the rows and columns mixed up. Change it to this:

```
function transpose(matrix) {
  var transposed = [],
    rows = matrix[0].length, // Changed here
    cols = matrix.length;    // and here

  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    transposed[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      transposed[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
    }
  }

  return transposed;
}

let result = transpose([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: but matrix[0].length=3 is number of columns and matrix.length=2 is number of rows. it's better to change inside loop ig. I want to be able to do using that way instead of looping first for columns.

Comment: The start matrix has two rows and three columns, so the transposed matrix will have three rows and two columns. That is why you need to change it to the above to resolve the error and get a correctly transposed matrix as a result. I don't understand, what you mean with "looping first for columns". If you have another question, either update your question here or post another one, if you can't find an answer to it.

Comment: it's alright. thanks for the answer.